# Where can I find resources on Gas Furnace manufacturers

Tags: heating, furnace, central-heating, gas

We are going to replace a 30 year old residential gas furnace. We have estimates for furnaces from Rheem, Trane and Bryant. This is a rental, so we aren't going for the 95% with tax rebate but standard 80. Looking for information about these three manufacturers.

Comment: Dear StackOverflow: we should be able to edit questions. I can't find a way. I'd like to add "furnace" as a tag... :-/

Comment: Hey @kegill! There should be an `edit` link just under the tags... Is it not there? (you need to be logged in)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for reviews or just general information about the furnaces?

This website has [consumer reviews](http://www.consumersearch.com/furnaces):

http://www.consumersearch.com/furnaces

Here is information about [Rheem](http://www.rheem.com/products/heating_and_cooling/gas_furnaces/) furnaces:

http://www.rheem.com/products/heating_and_cooling/gas_furnaces/

Here is information about [Trane](http://www.trane.com/residential/products/furnaces) furnaces:

http://www.trane.com/residential/products/furnaces

Here is information about [Bryant](http://www.bryant.com/products/furnaces/gas/index.shtml) furnaces:

http://www.bryant.com/products/furnaces/gas/index.shtml